# Migration 100 TB of data from SQL Server 2008 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We are planning to migrate to 100 TB of data from one of our client to new SQL Server environment. We just started receiving information from client. It will take couple of months to complete the project. But, can anyone please provide detail plan for migration such a large number of SQL Servers and data. New environment will have 4 fail-over cluster node at 4 different location.

- Current environment: SQL Server 2008 R2
- New environment : SQL Server 2014/16

Comment: I'm concerned that you are asking such a basic question with such a large project.  Haven't you done this before?  Is it the scale that's making you worried?  Break it down into smaller steps and go from there.

Answer (score 4):

The most important part of your question is:

> can anyone please provide detail plan for migration

And I've got great news: Microsoft used to build a really detailed [Upgrade Technical Guide (429-page PDF)](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/5/715BDFA7-51B6-4D7B-AF17-61E78C7E538F/SQL_Server_2014_Upgrade_technical_guide.pdf) that covered all kinds of details. They haven't updated it since 2014, but the information in there is still really useful for folks who are just starting from scratch and looking for guidance.

The bad news: SQL Server has only gotten more complicated since then. The 429-page length should help explain why it doesn't get updated frequently - it's expensive to build.